# Create-React-App: Can't trigger code coverage report from package.json script

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, code-coverage, create-react-app, babel-jest

I'm having some difficulty running full test coverage from a script in the `package.json` of my [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app). Link to repo [here](https://github.com/Norfeldt/react-kitchen-sink/);

> package.json

```
{
  "name": "React Kitchen Sink",
   ...
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts -r @cypress/instrument-cra start",
    "start:silent": "BROWSER=none yarn start",
    "start:server": "start-server-and-test start:silent http://localhost:3000",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",

    "jest:test": "react-scripts test --env=jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen",
    "jest:coverage": "react-scripts test --env=jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen --watchAll=false --coverage",
...
...
```

running

```
yarn jest:test
```

starts the test in watch mode with coverage and if I press `a` then I get a report with all test passing

but if I do

```
yarn jest:coverage
```

Then all test fails

The errors looks something like this:

```
 FAIL  src/components/Photo/index.test.js
  ● Console

    console.error node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/virtual-console.js:29
      Error: Uncaught [Error: Photo(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.]
          at reportException (/Users/norfeldt/Abtion/Playground/react-kitchen-sink/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/helpers/runtime-script-errors.js:62:24)
          at innerInvokeEventListeners (/Users/norfeldt/Abtion/Playground/react-kitchen-sink/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:333:9)
          at invokeEventListeners

...

      The above error occurred in the <Photo> component:
          in Photo (at Photo/index.test.js:32)
      
      Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
      Visit <link> to learn more about error boundaries.

  ● has a test id

    Photo(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.

...
```

Comment: What happens if you run that `react-scripts` command directly?

Comment: you mean without the `--env=jest..` ???

Comment: I mean instead of running `yar test:coverage`, try running `react-scripts test --env=jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen --watchAll=false --coverage`. (You might have to provide the full path to the `react-scripts` utility.) That would at least help narrow down the problem a bit.

Comment: @srk that is giving me the same failed test. I have updated my question to show some of the errors

Comment: @Norfeldt try upgrading `react-scripts` to version >=4.0.0 :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a known issue in `create-react-app` version >3.4.1, in which this bug happens when running `react-scripts test` with the flags `--watchAll=false` and `--coverage` at the same time. It was reported in [@facebook/create-react-app#8689](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8689)

The bug was later fixed by updating the `jest` version used in CRA to version >25 in the PR [@facebook/create-react-app#8362](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8362). The fix was included in the new major release of CRA, version 4.0.0.

Therefore, you should **upgrade your `react-scripts` package to version >=4.0.0** and then follow [this migration guide](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#migrating-from-34x-to-400) (to see if there are any breaking changes that affects you) and then the problem should be fixed.

In your case, I have downloaded your repo and done the following:

1. Deleted `node_modules` folder.
2. Upgraded the `react-scripts` to version 4.0.0 by executing this command `yarn add --exact react-scripts@4.0.0` (could be a later 4.x version too).
3. Run `yarn install` again.
4. Finally, tried again `yarn test:coverage` and it worked like a charm:

[image: Image of jest:coverage working]

If someone else is reading this and upgrading to version 4.0.0 is not an option for some reason, a short term easy fix would be to either:

- Remove the flag `--watchAll=false` and run it like this: `react-scripts test --env=jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen --coverage`
- Or downgrade `react-scripts` to version 3.4.0.

Answer (score 1):

Try this script

```
react-scripts test --collectCoverage
```

Comment: that triggers a watch mode and if I press `a` then all test fails